# Get osgi service reference from pure osgi bundle in Liferay portlet

Tags: mongodb, liferay, osgi, amdatu

I have successfully register the org.amdatu.mongo service in apche felix like shown below,
[image]

Bundle is shown below which export the service which is in active/running state.

[image]

Now I want to use this service in my portlet and I have return below code,

```
 package com.example.portlet;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.portlet.Portlet;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;

import org.amdatu.mongo.MongoDBService;
import org.apache.felix.dm.annotation.api.ServiceDependency;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample",
        "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
        "javax.portlet.display-name=loveworld Portlet",
        "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
        "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
        "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
        "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user"
    },
    service = Portlet.class
)
public class LoveworldmvcportletPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
     @ServiceDependency
     private volatile MongoDBService m_mongoDbService;



    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
            throws IOException, PortletException {
        System.out.println( m_mongoDbService);//**getting NULL**
        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }
}
```

I have tried with annotation  @ServiceDependency no luck getting null.My mongoDb server is running fine!!

I have Menifest.mf file as below,

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Bnd-LastModified: 1469380000381

Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2

Bundle-Name: loveworld

Bundle-SymbolicName: loveworld

Bundle-Version: 1.0.0

Created-By: 1.8.0_51 (Oracle Corporation)

Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc;version=

 "[1.0,2)",javax.portlet;version="[2.0,3)",javax.servlet,javax.servlet

 .http,org.amdatu.mongo;version="1.0.0"

Javac-Debug: on

Javac-Deprecation: off

Javac-Encoding: UTF-8

Private-Package: com.example.portlet,content

Provide-Capability: osgi.service;objectClass:List<String>="javax.portl

 et.Portlet",liferay.resource.bundle;bundle.symbolic.name=loveworld;re

 source.bundle.base.name="content.Language"

Require-Capability: osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib

 )(uri=http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0))",osgi.extender;filter:="(&(os

 gi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=http://liferay.com/tld/aui))",osgi.extend

 er;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=http://liferay.com/tld/p

 ortlet))",osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=htt

 p://liferay.com/tld/theme))",osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=

 jsp.taglib)(uri=http://liferay.com/tld/ui))",osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi

 .ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

Service-Component: OSGI-INF/com.example.portlet.LoveworldmvcportletPor

 tlet.xml

Tool: Bnd-3.2.0.201605172007
```

bnd.bnd file is as below,

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: loveworld
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc;version="[1.0,2)",javax.portlet;version="[2.0,3)",javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http,org.amdatu.mongo;version="1.0.0"
```

Portlet which consume the service is as shown below,

[image]

Comment: But here it shows that we can use directly take a look.http://www.amdatu.org/components/mongodb.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem: the service provided by your bundle is of type `ManagedServiceFactory`. You are trying to inject a service of type `MongoDBService`. This obviously doesn't match.

Second problem: you should not be trying to directly consume `ManagedServiceFactory` yourself... it is part of the Config Admin specification, and should only be consumed by Config Admin itself.

Third problem: as Balazs points out, you are using annotations from a mixture of different frameworks: Declarative Services (DS) and Dependency Manager (DM). These cannot be mixed within a single component... pick one!

Comment: I'll change the annonation to @reference???But here it shows that we can use directly take a look.http://www.amdatu.org/components/mongodb.html

Comment: @AbhishekSuthar In the example the Component annotation comes from  org.apache.felix.dm.annotation.api package. The first issue was that you mixed the two technologies (Declarative Services and Dependency Manager).

Comment: Yes you should use @Reference but even if you do this you still need to address the other two problems.

Comment: Ok but how to tackle second problem...how to get service from config admin?

Comment: You don't get services from config admin. You get the service of the type you're actually looking for, which is probably `MongoDBService`. Is there such a service?

Comment: I think so because on this link they have provided the code how to use that service http://www.amdatu.org/components/mongodb.html   and they are using like the way I have written.

Comment: There is no need to guess about this. Can you see a `MongoDBService` service listed in the console, or can't you?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the following two annotations:

```
import org.apache.felix.dm.annotation.api.ServiceDependency;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
```

One of them is the standard OSGi annotation for Declarative Services components, the other one from the Felix Dependency Manager project. Be sure that you use annotations only from *org.osgi.service.component.annotations* package.

Also, you should add a bind method to your component for the service reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Balazs.Understand your point...It would be helpful if you provide two or three line code...

Comment: I have tried with bundleActivator interface by implementing start stop method just for verification..return the code to get the mongoservice ...but In that case also Im getting null.

Comment: Here is a tutorial for Declarative Services: http://enroute.osgi.org/services/org.osgi.service.component.html

Comment: Its saying use reference annotation ...for any service but still im getting null

Comment: Do you have a bind method for the member variable (e.g.: a setter)? Did you specify the annotation on the bind method?

Comment: Means I have to define bind method as well in addition to reference annotation? Can you provide snippet for the same...

Comment: If you put the Reference annotation over a setter, the setter will be handled as the bind method. It means, that the setter will be called during the activation of the component.

Comment: I have to create setter ?Right...Ill do that and update the question

Comment: You don't need a bind method if you are using DS 1.3. Direct injection into fields is supported.